# Question about Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

> > $(X_n)$ is a sequence of $L^2$ random variables with $EX_n=0$ for all $n$ and suppose there is a constant $c$ s.t. $\operatorname{Var}(X_{n+k}−X_n)\leq ck$, for all $n,k\geq0$. Show that $X_n/n$ converges to $0$ a.s. (Hint: First prove along a suitable subsequence).

I can see that we are trying to make the probabilities summable along a subsequence but may I know how to choose a subsequence so that the upper bound we use for variance makes the probabilities summable?

$$P(|X_{n_k}|>nϵ)≤\operatorname{Var}(X_{n_k})/{n_k}^2ϵ^2\leq?$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Borel Cantelli lemma ?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use that with summability

Comment: You first need to complete your inequality with an upper bound on the variance as given in the problem.

Comment: If it helps you can use $(a+b)^2\leq 2a^2+2b^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \| X \|_2 $ denote the $ L^2 $ norm of $ X $. Note that if $ EX = 0 $, then $ \| X \|_2^2 = \operatorname{Var}(X) $.

Consider the subsequence given by $ n_k = 2^k $. Then,
$$ 
|\| X_{2^{k + 1}} \|_2 - \| X_{2^k} \|_2| \leq \| X_{2^{k + 1}} - X_{2^k} \|_2 $$
by the reverse triangle inequality. Squaring and using the given condition yields
$$
|\| X_{2^{k + 1}} \|_2 - \| X_{2^k} \|_2|^2 \leq c2^k
$$
Since $ \| X_{2^k} \|_2 \geq 0 $, it follows that
$$
\| X_{2^{k + 1}} \|_2 \leq \| X_{2^k} \|_2 + \sqrt{c}2^{k / 2}
$$
By induction, it follows that
$$
\| X_{2^{k + 1}} \|_2 \leq \| X_1 \|_2 + \sqrt{2c}\frac{2^{k / 2} - 1}{\sqrt{2} - 1}
$$
Finally,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X_{n_k}) / n_k^2 \leq
\left(
\| X_1 \|_2 2^{-k} + \sqrt{2c}2^{-k}\frac{2^{(k - 1) / 2} - 1}{\sqrt{2} - 1}
\right)^2 = O(2^{-k})
$$
so $ \operatorname{Var}(X_{n_k}) / n_k^2 $ is summable.